# permissions error with localhost

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, permission-denied

My httpd.conf file looks like this

```
    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When I open up localhost on a browser it displays, "It Works!" but when I do localhost/~username I get the error 403 forbidden you don't have permission to access /~username/ on this server
any ideas on how to fix this, or what is causing it?

Comment: which OS/distribution are you using? Did you look online, it sound like a common issue.

Comment: I am using Mountain Lion and I have looked and none of them seem to be working

Comment: did you read [Per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html) ?

Comment: did you enable `mod_userdir` module?

Comment: Step 1 would be to read the error log -- this will tell you if it's a filesystem permissions issue (permission denied) or a server configuration issue.